# How to plot coordinates on tmap output?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tmap

So far, I have managed to visually present data for different socio-economic factors at a district level in Pakistan with the help of the `tmap` package to create the following output:

[image]

```r
accesstowater <- tm_shape(pak) + 
    tm_fill("Condition", n = 5, palette = "-Blues", colorNA = "grey",
             textNA = "Missing Values", title = "Access to Water") + 
    tm_borders(alpha = 0.5) +
    tm_credits("Source: PBS - PSLM 2014 - 15\nDH Corp Ltd.", size = .64,
                position = c(.62,0.02))
```

In the code above, `pak` is the name of my Spatial Dataframe and `Condition` is a variable within that dataframe showing access to water.

---

At the same time, I have used the `ggplot2` package to plot the geographic coordinates of various towers for different Mobile Network Operators in Pakistan (roughly 13000 towers). The output is as follows:

[image]

```r
pakTowers <- ggmap(pakmap6) + 
               geom_point(aes(Longitude, Latitude, colour = MNO), 
                          data = Towers, size = 0.7, alpha = 0.5,
                          show.legend = FALSE)
```

In the code above , `pakmap6` is the output of the `get-map()` function, `MNO` represents the Mobile Network Operator and the `Towers` dataset includes entries for each tower's coordinates.

My next requirement is to overlay the second plot over the first, essentially showing the towers on top of the district wise electricity scores.

Any ideas on which packages I could use (as well as sample code) in order to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That's an interesting question but difficult to answer without code and data. Please, [edit] your question and add your code and sample data to create a minimal reproducible example. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I've added more code to the data. How else can I make my question more comprehensive?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have your shapefiles, so I cannot reproduce it, but it should definitely be possible with tmap alone:

```
pak_osm <- read_osm(pak, ext=1.1) # reads OSM data based on the bounding box of pak with 10 percent extension

qtm(pak_osm) +
tm_shape(pak) + 
tm_fill("Condition", n = 5, palette = "-Blues", colorNA = "grey", 
    textNA = "Missing Values", title = "Access to Water") + 
tm_borders(alpha = 0.5) + 
tm_credits("Source: PBS - PSLM 2014 - 15\nDH Corp Ltd.", size = .64, position = c(.62,0.02)) +
tm_shape(Towers) +
tm_symbols(color="MNO", shape="MNO", alpha=0.5)
```

Please let me know if this is what you had in mind.

PS: It required version 1.6, which I submitted to CRAN today:) You can also install the development version:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("mtennekes/tmap", subdir = "pkg")
```